# Cannot install pytable

Tags: python

I'm trying to install pytable using either pycharm or pip but both attempts give the error "Conflicting Dependecies". And "The conflict is caused by : pytable 0.8.23a0 depends on basicproperty>=0.6.9a". So I tried installing the basicproperty version using pycharm and pip and it gave the error "[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KdBsF.png)Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement basicproperty (from versions: none)".What to do?

Comment: These packages are nearly 15 years old and were built for Python 2.2. I don't think you will be able to get this working.

Comment: The [package site](http://pytable.sourceforge.net/) has a link to install BasicProperty via source forge. Have you tried that?

Answer (score 0):

Can you try;

```
pip install pytables
```

Pytables is python hosted project. For install guide;

https://www.pytables.org/usersguide/installation.html

Answer (score 0):

You should try `python3 -m pip install tables` or `pip install tables`

https://www.pytables.org/usersguide/installation.html